# Invoking a WPF view (UserControl) method from the main window (Window)

Tags: wpf

I have a button on a view (UserControl) that invokes a method in the code-behind file.  I would like to get rid of the button and instead, invoke the method from a menu item.  Not sure how to do this.  Here is some simple code illustrating this situation:

MainWindow.xaml (MainView is embedded):

```
<Window x:Class="Example.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:View="clr-namespace:Example.View"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800"  Background="Green">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="File" Click="MenuItem_Click">
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <View:MainView/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Example
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("MainWindow");

        // how can I invoke MainView methods like DoWork from here?
    }
  }
}
```

MainView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Example.View.MainView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="600">

<Grid Background="Yellow">
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10" Content="Show" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>

</UserControl>
```

MainView.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Example.View
{
  public partial class MainView : UserControl
  {
    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoWork();
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("MainView");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Since you work in wpf have you thought about MVVM pattern?

Comment: Using MVVM, would you have some sort of property in the View that would trigger some behavior and set that property from the main window?

Comment: I would say, that DoWork belongs to ViewModel and if it is mandatory necessary to trigger something in usercontrol, then via VieModel layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just give a name to the MainView,

```
<Window x:Class="Example.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:View="clr-namespace:Example.View"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800"  Background="Green">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Menu>
                <MenuItem Header="File" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
            </Menu>
            <View:MainView x:Name="mainView"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and call the Method like this:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mainView.DoWork();
}
```

Comment: I tried this suggestion but the DoWork method is not available. I can only access DoWork if I make it static and call it like this, Example.View.MainView.DoWork();

Comment: It works for me. Is the DoWork() in the UserControl public?

Comment: @rrrrrrr If this is the answer that worked for you then please mark it as such.